# Docusign API Custom Button with SFDC - giving error

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a custom button for Sales to drive a custom routing and I'm getting the following error: "A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:   Unexpected identifier"

Here is the text of the button.   I'm having a hard time troubleshooting this, because the error is rather vague.

Here's the Code:

`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} var RC='';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CRL='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';RC='';RSL='2';RSRO='';RROS='';CCRM=''CRCL='';CRL='Email~matt.moog@powerreviews.com;FirstName~Matt;LastName~Moog;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2;Email~legal@powerreviews.com;FirstName~Legal;LastName~Department;Role~Carbon Copy;RoutingOrder~'Email~{!Opportunity.OwnerEmail};FirstName~{!Opportunity.OwnerFirstName};LastName~{!Opportunity.OwnerLastName};Role~Carbon Copy;RoutingOrder~3';CCTM='';CCNM='';CRCL='';OCO='';DST='';LA='0';CEM='Hello,I am sending you this request for your electronic signature, please review and electronically sign by following the link below.We highly recommend that you use the electronic signature to speed the process, however, if you do need to sign manually, please click the MORE button at the top of the Docusign screen and select the "Sign on Paper" option - and complete the process as defined in the dialog box in Docusign.   Otherwise, there may be delays in the execution of this process.We appreciate your cooperation.';CES='PowerReviews Request to eSign Contracts - {!Account.Name}';STB='1';SSB='1';SES='1';SEM='1';SRS='1';SCS='1';RES='1,2,2,1,15,3';window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;`

Comment: Whoever keeps downvoting questions, please comment as to why you downvoted so the poster can improve his question.

Comment: I also up-voted one of the down-votes because I don't believe this was an inadequate question.

Answer (score 2):

You have `CCRM=''CRCL='';` it needs to be changed to `CCRM='';CRCL='';`

Comment: Thanks SOOOOO much.   I looked at this for over an hour and didn't find this.   Appreciate it.

Comment: I know the DocuSign documentation says to leave everything on one line. In most cases this isn't needed. I recommend creating your call spaced out and then removing spaces if you want to follow the DocuSign best practices.